# Redirect domain

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-6, virtualhost, rewrite

I am setting up a couple micro sites that I would like to have their own url associated with.  How can I redirect that url to a sub folder of an existing site?

for example, i might like to redirect http:/www.applesandstuff.com/ => http://www.cheeseandstuff.com/applesandstuff/

Comment: Yes, sorry should have included the server; IIS 6.0
I think I may just use the host header redirection route suggested by mpbloch.

Comment: This how, for example, Office Live Small Business, and Google Apps for custom domains work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have control of how the Web server handles requests at www.cheeseandstuff.com.

You then set up a conditional based on the HOST header, and set up a redirect to the path.

In your dns, you can use a CNAME to redirect "www" in applesandstuff.com to "www.cheeseandstuff.com". **Or**, to "applesandstuff.www.cheeseandstuff.com", for example, and set up your redirects on the web server to look for "(MATCH).www.cheeseandstuff.com" and redirect to the path "/(MATCH)".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in apache with mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule   ^www\.applesandstuff\.org(.*)$      http://www.cheeseandstuff.org/applesandstuff$1 [NC,R,L]
```

About the flags:

- NC: Not case sensitive
- R: Redirect, change the url shown to the user. This is the opposite of proxy [P]
- L: Final redirect, Don't apply any other rules if this matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a basic 301 redirect in your .htaccess file that says something like the following:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.cheeseandstuff.com/applesandstuff
```

That will take anything going from the root of the site and redirect it to your other site

Answer (score 0):

Request for more information: what web server are you using to serve the sites?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache you want to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other posters, it really depends on what web server you are using. Even within IIS there are multiple ways to do it depending on which version of IIS you are running.